# Terraform depends_on

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a plan that performs the following

1. Create private key (This tf file is located on the root)
2. main file that runs an ec2-instance-module (the module are located inside the module folder)
3. ec2-instance resource (this is what the module is running). One of the tasks is to copy a file (using a provisioner file) , The provisioner is using a connection based on a private key that should be created on stage 1. when I'm running the plan, it failed, If I will put the remark on the provisioner file run the terraform (all is working and the file is created) and after that, I will include the provisioner file - it will work since the files already exists.  I have tried to add **"depends_on = [local_file.key]"** to the ec2 resource instance but it didn't work

**## Create Key file - located on the root folder ##**

```
resource "tls_private_key" "key" {
         algorithm = "RSA"
         rsa_bits  = 4096 
}
    
resource "aws_key_pair" "key" {
       key_name   = "project_key"
       public_key = tls_private_key.key.public_key_openssh
}
    
resource "local_file" "key" {
       sensitive_content  = tls_private_key.key.private_key_pem
       filename           = "key.pem"
}
```

**## Main file that runs the module located on the root folder ##**

```
module "ansible-server"{
     source = "./modules/ansible-server"
     ami_id = "ami-04505e7fdc0741db8d"
     instance_type = var.ansible_server_instance-type
     availability_zone = var.availability_zone[0]
     subnet_id = module.public_subnet.publicsubnetid[0]
     vpc_id = module.vpc.vpcid
     key_name  = aws_key_pair.key.key_name

}
```

**## Ec2 instance - located under modules/ansible-server/main.tf ##**

```
resource "aws_instance" "ansible_server" {
  ami               = var.ami_id
  instance_type     = var.instance_type
  availability_zone = var.availability_zone
  subnet_id = var.subnet_id
  vpc_security_group_ids  = [aws_security_group.ansible_server.id]
  key_name = var.key_name
  provisioner "file" {
    source     = "key.pem"
    destination = "/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa"
    connection {   
      host        = self.public_ip
      user        = "user"
      private_key = file("key.pem")      
    }   
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `depends_on` should be on the module:

```
module "ansible-server"{
     source = "./modules/ansible-server"
     ami_id = "ami-04505e7fdc0741db8d"
     instance_type = var.ansible_server_instance-type
     availability_zone = var.availability_zone[0]
     subnet_id = module.public_subnet.publicsubnetid[0]
     vpc_id = module.vpc.vpcid
     key_name  = aws_key_pair.key.key_name

     depends_on = [local_file.key]
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error 



Error: Invalid function argument
│ 
│   on modules/ansible-server/main.tf line 15, in resource "aws_instance" "ansible_server":
│   15:       private_key = file("key.pem")      
│ 
│ Invalid value for "path" parameter: no file exists at "key.pem"; this function works only with files that are distributed as part of the configuration
│ source code, so if this file will be created by a resource in this configuration you must instead obtain this result from an attribute of that resource.